# Changing date format to a specific format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my application I have date coming in an ISO String format: '2020-12-20T15:21:28.411Z'
In the database the value is stored as: '2020-12-20 15:21:28+411'.

So how can I convert '2020-12-20T15:21:28.411Z' -> '2020-12-20 15:21:28+411'.

I don't want to use moment.js and .toLocaleString() does not work.

Comment: How about you find a way to delete T in the date and replace with a space, then the last part, add a "+" and delete the last letter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date is in the string format, you can replace the dot with a + and the T with a space, then chop off the last character:

```
yourDate.replace(/\./g,"+").replace(/T/g," ").slice(0,-1)
```